# How to install Counter-Strike 1.6 on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: steam

Just wanted to ask how can I install CS 1.6 on Ubuntu 13.04. I couldn't install by using Steam. Thanks !

Comment: From what I recall you cannot run CS 1.6 natively on Ubuntu. You'll have to use wine or another *win*dows *e*mulator... Not sure about this though.

Comment: There is native Steam working on Ubuntu but Counter-Strike is not listed.

Comment: Both Counter Strike and Counter Strike Source are provided natively through Steam on Linux http://store.steampowered.com/app/10 . I tried them and they worked with no problem.

Comment: I can run CS 1.6 natively from Steam on Linux.

Comment: If you're still experiencing this problem, *what happens exactly* when you try to install it using Steam?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CounterStrike

Answer (score 2):

Download steam installer for linux from steam official site. Through steam you will be able to install CS 1.6. Its working for me. But, however, I am looking for portable CS 1.6 build that can run on Linux/Ubuntu. Because, Its looks like Steam/CS 1.6 having some issues with firewall. I often get disconnected from the game & I get some message telling me to relax firewall rules.

If you know to work around this issue, then you should be good with Steam/CS 1.6.